Color figure number in list of figures but not in figure caption
I'm making a tex document that is required to have a certain color scheme for the table of contents. I would like to make it so that within the List of Figures, the figure number is colored, but the figure caption is not changed and, the rest of the TOC color scheme is left untouched. Also, the color of the figure number within the document should not be changed.
Incidentally, if I could find a way to color blue the entirety of the figure captions (including "Figure 1:") within the document, then that would be even better, but is not strictly necessary for my purposes.
The best I have been able to do is color things using hyperref, but this has undesirable side-effects on the rest of the TOC and LOF.
Here's my (not so minimal) MWE.
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=11pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%
% unholy incantation
%
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}
{\cftsecfont #1}%    search pattern
{\cftsecfont {#1}}%  replace by
{}%                  success
{}%                  failure
\makeatother

\newcommand{\secmacro}[1]{\color{orange}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\secmacro}

\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\color{orange}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\color{orange}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\color{orange}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\color{orange}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\color{orange}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{2} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0em}  
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{6em}  
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\textcolor{orange}{Figure}\hfill} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{\hspace{1.5 em}} 

\newcommand{\switchtoblack}{
    \newpagecolor{black}
    \color{white}
}

\newcommand{\switchtowhite}{
    \newpagecolor{white}
    \color{black}
}
%
% COLORS FIG NUMBERS BUT HAS BAD SIDE-EFFECTS
%
%\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor = orange, urlcolor = orange, linkcolor = orange]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
\switchtoblack

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\newpage

\switchtowhite

\section{Now this is a story}

All about how

\subsection{My life got flipped}

Turned upside down

%
% CAPTION IS COLORED, BUT "Figure 1:" IS NOT
%
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    I'd like to take a minute
    \caption{\textcolor{blue}{Just sit right there}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    I'll tell you how I became the prince
    \caption{Of a town called Bel-Air}
\end{figure}

\end{document}






There is no paper=letter nor fontsize=11pt for the article class.

@egreg Wait, so are those options are being ignored? How do I set the font size or paper size then?

The options are letterpaper (that's the default so it can be omitted) and 11pt. They've been so for 30 years.

@egreg I think I had known that at some point... Anyway, thank you!

You're probably confusing with the options for scrartcl and the like.

You're setting up \cftfigpresnum to typeset an orange "Figure", you only need a very small adjustment to also colour the number: \cftfigpresnum is used in front of the number and \cftfigaftersnum is used after it. Just use \color instead of \textcolor there. To make sure that nothing leaks you can also put \begingroup and \endgroup in the two hooks.
To get blue figure captions in the text but not the LoF you can use the caption package and its font option (which you then pass color=blue).
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=11pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={color=blue}}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%
% unholy incantation
%
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}
{\cftsecfont #1}%    search pattern
{\cftsecfont {#1}}%  replace by
{}%                  success
{}%                  failure
\makeatother

\newcommand{\secmacro}[1]{\color{orange}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\secmacro}

\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\color{orange}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\color{orange}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\color{orange}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\color{orange}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\color{orange}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{2} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0em}  
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{6em}  
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\begingroup\color{orange}{Figure}\hfill} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{\endgroup\hspace{1.5 em}} 

\newcommand{\switchtoblack}{
    \newpagecolor{black}
    \color{white}
}

\newcommand{\switchtowhite}{
    \newpagecolor{white}
    \color{black}
}
%
% COLORS FIG NUMBERS BUT HAS BAD SIDE-EFFECTS
%
%\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor = orange, urlcolor = orange, linkcolor = orange]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
\switchtoblack

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\newpage

\switchtowhite

\section{Now this is a story}

All about how

\subsection{My life got flipped}

Turned upside down

%
% CAPTION IS COLORED, BUT "Figure 1:" IS NOT
%
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    I'd like to take a minute
    \caption{\textcolor{blue}{Just sit right there}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    I'll tell you how I became the prince
    \caption{Of a town called Bel-Air}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

LoF:

Figure captions:


Incredible, thank you!
